# SparkR 2.0 Classification: how to get performance matrices?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

How to get performance matrices in sparkR classification, e.g., F1 score, Precision, Recall, Confusion Matrix

```r
# Load training data
df <- read.df("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt", source = "libsvm")
training <- df
 testing <- df

# Fit a random forest classification model with spark.randomForest
model <- spark.randomForest(training, label ~ features, "classification", numTrees = 10)

# Model summary
  summary(model)

 # Prediction
  predictions <- predict(model, testing)
  head(predictions)

 # Performance evaluation
```

I've tried `caret::confusionMatrix(testing$label,testing$prediction)` it shows error:

```r
   Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) :   unique() applies only to vectors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caret's `confusionMatrix` will not work, since it needs R dataframes while your data are in Spark dataframes.

One **not** recommended way for getting your metrics is to "collect" locally your Spark dataframes to R using [`as.data.frame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/R/as.data.frame.html), and then use `caret` etc.; but this means that your data can fit in the main memory of your driver machine, in which case of course you have absolutely no reason to use Spark...

So, here is a way to get the accuracy in a distributed manner (i.e. without collecting data locally), using the `iris` data as an example:

```r
sparkR.version()
# "2.1.1"

df <- as.DataFrame(iris)
model <- spark.randomForest(df, Species ~ ., "classification", numTrees = 10)
predictions <- predict(model, df)
summary(predictions)
# SparkDataFrame[summary:string, Sepal_Length:string, Sepal_Width:string, Petal_Length:string, Petal_Width:string, Species:string, prediction:string]

createOrReplaceTempView(predictions, "predictions")
correct <- sql("SELECT prediction, Species FROM predictions WHERE prediction=Species")
count(correct)
# 149
acc = count(correct)/count(predictions)
acc
# 0.9933333
```

(Regarding the 149 correct predictions out of 150 samples, if you do a `showDF(predictions, numRows=150)` you will see indeed that there is a single `virginica` sample misclassified as `versicolor`).